# Troubles with wrong characters in neovim+tmux

Tags: gnome-terminal, tmux, neovim

I have a problem with extra charaters displayed in my nvim.
It works ok until I open a tmux or guake terminal.
This looks like next picture(I just wrote :q, but got that strange symbols)
[strange symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FvKaf.png)

Comment: What's your `gnome-terminal` version? Looks like a bit older one. The escape sequence `\e[6 q` sets the cursor to a certain shape, and apparently it's not yet supported. Support was introduced in VTE 0.40 which pairs with GNOME 3.16.

Comment: @egmont
version 3.14.1

Comment: That probably means VTE 0.38. It should be safe to replace it with 0.40, should you really want this feature of neovim toggling between two different cursor shapes. Or try to configure neovim not to change the cursor shape.

Comment: @egmont thanx a lot, it helped:)